# What exactly is the "fetches" parameter in the Session.run( ) function in tensorflow 1?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, training-data

I am reviewing some code written in tensorflow 1 that uses a neural network to modulate the weights of a second neural network. The code for the training loop (for every epoch) is the following:

```
feed_dict = {self.nn_X: batch_xs, self.nn_Y: batch_ys, self.nn_lr_c: clr, self.nn_wd_c: wdc}
                l, www, _, = self.sess.run([self.loss, self.comps[0].output, self.optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                avg_cost_train += l / self.total_batch
```

My question is, what exactly does the array in the first parameter of the sess.run function do?

The first attribute of the array is the loss of the network (y - second net's output), the second is the output of the first net that modulates the second's weights, and the third is the AdamW optimizer. The documentation I found was really bad and I can't understand what exactly does the session.run function do with the "fetches" parameter apart from just training the model.

The feed_dict is the training data input, output, learning rate and weight decay for the AdamW optimizer.